# undefined reference to omp_get_thread_num using OpenMP and cmake?

Tags: c++, unix, makefile, cmake, openmp

I am using a large code-base that compiled successfully before using `make` with a makefile and cmake. However, now that I'm trying to use openmp with it, I'm now getting the errors

```
undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
```

I don't think this is a problem with tthe CMakeLists.txt file, because I created a seperate directory and successfully built and compiled a helloworld OpenMP program. So what is causing this error?

I edited the CMakeLists.txt in `project/src/project` so to include `-fopenmp` so it contains the line

```
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -pedantic -Wextra -fopenmp")
 ....
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(PROJECT  ${OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES} ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS}).
```

The CMakeLists.txt already has the lines

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenMP)
  if(OPENMP_FOUND)
     message("OPENMP FOUND")
     set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
     set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
     set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
  endif()
 include_directories(SYSTEM ${OpenMP_INCLUDE_PATH})
```

Comment: Literally copied what you wrote and everything worked just fine. Have you checked cmake output to see if OpenMP is being found? Do you compile verbosely to see that `PROJECT` gets compiled with the right flags?

Comment: I am fairly new to Unix. Where can I check the cmake output, and what is the file name? After I type `make VERBOSE=1`, how can I check if `project` is compiling with the right flags?

Comment: Cmake output is what you find when you run `cmake ..` from the build directory (typically a subdirectory of the project directory called `build`). You should see a message saying something like `-- Found OpenMP: -fopenmp`. Then you can run `make PROJECT VERBOSE=1` to see what commands get executed in the compilation process.

Comment: after typing `cmake`, I did see `-- Found OpenMP: -fopenmp`. Typing `make PROJECT VERBOSE=1` gives `make: *** No rule to make target `PROJECT'.  Stop.`. Just `make VERBOSE=1` outputs a ton of stuff, so I don't know how to check if its compiling with the right flags or not